# What is the name of functions written like below in JavaScript, and what is their purpose? I would like to learn more about them

Tags: javascript, function

```
var output = (function(x) { 
//do something with x 
return x; })
(0);
```

I don't get what x is being passed in as or where its being passed in. Maybe this is not written correctly.

Comment: `x` is the argument, in this case `0`. It's passed when the function is called (`(0)` as in `fn(0)` - but instead of first assigning the function expression to a variable `fn`, it is used without a name and immediately called, just like I can write `'abc'.toUpperCase()` without first assigning `'abc'` to some variable). The name of this construct is **IIFE** (immediately-invoked function expression). It is sometimes used to create an isolated scope and to allow easy short-circuiting with `return`.

Comment: MDN Web Docs: [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: IIFE with function expression so to say

Comment: @CherryDT thank you for the response, makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @ratyacatnug "immediately-invoked function expression with function expression"...? - I think you fell victim to the [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) here ;-)

Comment: @CherryDT sorry bro. in addition its main usage in 'module' patern and writing safe code, in other means encapsulation